# Problem in Uploading through Visual Studio

Tags: compile, arduino-galileo, visualstudio

This is my simple program:

```cpp
int led = 13;
void setup()
{
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  /* add setup code here */

}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  /* add main program code here */

}
```

I tried to upload it using Visual Studio 2013 using a plugin **Visual Micro** for **Arduino**. But it resulted in this error:

```
Compiling 'bb' for 'Intel® Galileo Gen2'
Binary sketch size: 83,455 bytes (used 1% of a 10,000,000 byte maximum) (0.17 secs)
Compiling debug version of 'bb' for 'Intel® Galileo Gen2'
Binary sketch size: 85,056 bytes (used 1% of a 10,000,000 byte maximum) (2.81 secs)
Uploading to I/O board using 'COM3'
starting download script
Args to shell: C:\arduino-1.5.3-Intel.1.0.4/hardware/tools/x86/bin C:\Users\Shiran Abbasi\AppData\Local\V.Micro\Arduino\Builds\bb\izmir_fg/bb.elf COM3
COM PORT Abbasi\AppData\Local\V.Micro\Arduino\Builds\bb\izmir_fg/bb.elf
Converted COM Port Abbasi\AppData\Local\V.Micro\Arduino\Builds\bb\izmir_fg/bb.elf to tty port
Sending Command String to move to download if not already in download mode
Deleting existing sketch on target
Moving downloaded file to /sketch/sketch.elf on target

#!/bin/sh

echo "starting download script"
echo "Args to shell:" $*

# ARG 1: Path to lsz executable.
# ARG 2: Elf File to download
# ARG 3: COM port to use.

#path contains \ need to change all to /
path_to_exe=$1
fixed_path=${path_to_exe//\\/\/}

#COM ports are not always setup to be addressed via COM for redirect.
#/dev/ttySx are present. Howwever, COMy -> /dev/ttySx where x = y - 1

com_port_arg=$3
com_port_id=${com_port_arg/COM/}
echo "COM PORT" $com_port_id
tty_port_id=/dev/ttyS$((com_port_id-1))
C:\arduino-1.5.3-Intel.1.0.4/hardware/arduino/x86/tools/izmir/clupload_win.sh: line 20: Abbasi\AppData\Local\V.Micro\Arduino\Builds\bb\izmir_fg/bb.elf: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\AppData\Local\V.Micro\Arduino\Builds\bb\izmir_fg/bb.elf")
echo "Converted COM Port" $com_port_arg "to tty port" $tty_port_id

echo "Sending Command String to move to download if not already in download mode"
echo "~sketch download" > $tty_port_id
C:\arduino-1.5.3-Intel.1.0.4/hardware/arduino/x86/tools/izmir/clupload_win.sh: line 24: $tty_port_id: ambiguous redirect

#Move the existing sketch on target.
echo "Deleting existing sketch on target"
$fixed_path/lsz.exe --escape -c "mv -f /sketch/sketch.elf /sketch/sketch.elf.old"  $tty_port_id 1>&0
C:\arduino-1.5.3-Intel.1.0.4/hardware/arduino/x86/tools/izmir/clupload_win.sh: line 28: $tty_port_id: ambiguous redirect

# Execute the target download command

#Download the file.
host_file_name=$2
$fixed_path/lsz.exe --escape --binary --overwrite $host_file_name  $tty_port_id 1>&0
C:\arduino-1.5.3-Intel.1.0.4/hardware/arduino/x86/tools/izmir/clupload_win.sh: line 34: $tty_port_id: ambiguous redirect

#mv the downloaded file to /sketch/sketch.elf 
target_download_name="${host_file_name##*/}" 
echo "Moving downloaded file to /sketch/sketch.elf on target"
#$fixed_path/lsz.exe --escape -c "cp sketch /sketch/sketch.elf"  $tty_port_id 1>&0
$fixed_path/lsz.exe --escape -c "mv $target_download_name /sketch/sketch.elf; chmod +x /sketch/sketch.elf"  $tty_port_id 1>&0
C:\arduino-1.5.3-Intel.1.0.4/hardware/arduino/x86/tools/izmir/clupload_win.sh: line 40: $tty_port_id: ambiguous redirect
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: I see nothing that looks like an error in the output you posted. Is that all you got?

Comment: yeah it's all i got and it's very annoying because when i upload the same program using arduino ide, it gets uploaded successfully.

Comment: @jfpoilpret can u help me?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help as I think we are all lacking information here. First how do you know the upload went badly since there is no real error message? What I find strange in the output you psoeted is the shell script that has nothing to do here since you are on Windows...

Comment: You have to keep Visual Micro up to date when using new Ide's. The intel Ide functionality was evolving but has now been moved to the Arduino 1.6.2+ boards manager. Again, with the latest Visual Micro releases it is supported